# Authenticating a user with Cookies using Vanilla Forums

Tags: authentication, cookies

I'm running a forum on my website at mydomain.com/forums, which uses the Vanilla Framework.

However, I'd like users who are registered on that forum to be able to leave comments on other pages of my site, at mydomain.com/blog. So I need a way of checking that a user is logged in, or if not, a way of providing them with the Vanilla Login box.

My Vanilla Code is not on my blog pages at all, so I need some kind of extra script. After a lot of digging, I found this online, https://gist.github.com/lincolnwebs/700805 which gives the user_id if logged in or a 0 if not logged in. So it appears to work great, because I don't have to include the whole vanilla framework.

The script appears to be checking the value of a cookie on the user's browser. Could someone fake the value of the cookie and gain access to someone's account?

As a relative newbie, can someone explain if this is a safe and secure way to verify a user is logged in? It took me ages to find this, and it appears to be hidden away/not publicised. Also the script is not 100% perfect because it uses $this inside a static function.

Thanks

```
<?php
/**
 * @copyright Vanilla Forums Inc.
 * @license GNU GPL2
 */

/**
 * Instantiating this class will store current user's ID from cookie as $this->UserID.
 */
class VanillaIdentity {

   # Copy these from Vanilla config
   public $CookieName = 'Vanilla';
   public $CookieSalt = ''; 
   public $CookieHashMethod = 'md5';
   public $UserID = 0;

   /**
    * Returns the unique id assigned to the user in the database (retrieved
    * from the session cookie if the cookie authenticates) or FALSE if not
    * found or authentication fails.
    *
    * @return int
    */
   public function __construct() {         
      if (!$this->_CheckCookie($this->CookieName)) return 0;

      list($UserID, $Expiration) = $this->GetCookiePayload($this->CookieName);

      if (!is_numeric($UserID) || $UserID < -2) // allow for handshake special id
         $this->UserID = 0;
      else
         $this->UserID = $UserID;
   }

   public static function GetCookiePayload($CookieName) {
      if (!self::CheckCookie($CookieName)) return FALSE;

      $Payload = explode('|', $_COOKIE[$CookieName]);

      // Get rid of check fields like HashKey, HMAC and Time
      array_shift($Payload);
      array_shift($Payload);
      array_shift($Payload);

      return $Payload;
   }

   protected function _CheckCookie($CookieName) {
      return self::CheckCookie($CookieName);
   }

   public static function CheckCookie($CookieName) {

      if (empty($_COOKIE[$CookieName])) {
         return FALSE;
      }

      $CookieHashMethod = $this->CookieHashMethod;
      $CookieSalt = $this->CookieSalt;

      $CookieData = explode('|', $_COOKIE[$CookieName]);
      if (count($CookieData) < 5) {
         return FALSE;
      }

      list($HashKey, $CookieHash, $Time, $UserID, $Expiration) = $CookieData;
      if ($Expiration < time() && $Expiration != 0) {
         return FALSE;
      }

      $Key = self::_Hash($HashKey, $CookieHashMethod, $CookieSalt);
      $GeneratedHash = self::_HashHMAC($CookieHashMethod, $HashKey, $Key);

      if ($CookieHash != $GeneratedHash) {
         return FALSE;
      }

      return TRUE;
   }

   /**
    * Returns $this->_HashHMAC with the provided data, the default hashing method
    * (md5), and the server's COOKIE.SALT string as the key.
    *
    * @param string $Data The data to place in the hash.
    */
   protected static function _Hash($Data, $CookieHashMethod, $CookieSalt) {
      return Gdn_CookieIdentity::_HashHMAC($CookieHashMethod, $Data, $CookieSalt);
   }

   /**
    * Returns the provided data hashed with the specified method using the
    * specified key.
    *
    * @param string $HashMethod The hashing method to use on $Data. Options are MD5 or SHA1.
    * @param string $Data The data to place in the hash.
    * @param string $Key The key to use when hashing the data.
    */
   protected static function _HashHMAC($HashMethod, $Data, $Key) {
      $PackFormats = array('md5' => 'H32', 'sha1' => 'H40');

      if (!isset($PackFormats[$HashMethod]))
         return false;

      $PackFormat = $PackFormats[$HashMethod];
      // this is the equivalent of "strlen($Key) > 64":
      if (isset($Key[63]))
         $Key = pack($PackFormat, $HashMethod($Key));
      else
         $Key = str_pad($Key, 64, chr(0));

      $InnerPad = (substr($Key, 0, 64) ^ str_repeat(chr(0x36), 64));
      $OuterPad = (substr($Key, 0, 64) ^ str_repeat(chr(0x5C), 64));

      return $HashMethod($OuterPad . pack($PackFormat, $HashMethod($InnerPad . $Data)));
   }

}
```

Comment: What framework do you use for the authentication of mydomain.com/blog?

Comment: That's basically the crux of the issue. I currently don't have any authentication for the blog, but I'd like to use Vanilla's User Management software, so I want to use Vanilla to authenticate users outside of my forum.

Answer (score 2):

I am not Vanilla and JavaScript expert. I do understand well HTTP authentication and SSO and I will try to clarify couple of your questions.

First of all after an HTTP authentication an application set a user cookie to a browser. 
Upon next requests the browser sends a cookie to the server. Please note that is it important what path used during the set of the cookie. If the path is “/’ the browser sends the cookie to all applications on the server.

The cookie can be hijacked and used to access the application. Please note, that a hacker may not decrypt the cookie – just use it. See for details the following link: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_hijacking_attack. To prevent a session hijacking you can use HTTPS.

To solve your problem you need
1)  Use the same user repository both for mydomain.com/forums and for mydomain.com/blog
In this case user “bob” will be the same user for both applications.
2)  To ensure that Vanilla sets the cookie with the path  “/’ 
In this case the browser sends the cookie both for mydomain.com/forums and for mydomain.com/blog.

I have found the following Vanilla plugin – it may completely solve your problem:
http://vanillaforums.org/page/SingleSignOn

Hope it helps. Please comment if you need any additional clarifications.

Comment: Agreed. Also even if you can hijack the session without decrypting the cookie, you must encrypt it to prevent other attacks. Both VanillaIdentity and SingleSingOn(jsConnect) use md5 (default) or sha1. Both have been [broken](http://ehash.iaik.tugraz.at/wiki/The_Hash_Function_Zoo). So you can either adapt the libraries to use scrypt or bcrypt, or configure them to use sha1 with a good salt and hope for the best.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Is a cookie safe from being hijacked using scrpt or bcrypt?

Comment: The most secured way to protect a cookie hijacking is to use HTTPS